# User input from inputText stored as a variable

Tags: r, variables, shiny

I wish to take two user input from a inputText box and store them in a variable for later use after submitting with the actionButton.

Here is my UI:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sandbox"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(("Predictive Pick Date"),
      textInput("InputCI", "Enter confidence % level", "95"),
      textInput("InputReqDM", "Enter required DM %", "15"),
      actionButton("submit", "Submit")),

    mainPanel("Blocks")

  )
))
```

Here is my Server:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(splancs)
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session){ #pDMInput is the user input for what DM% they are aiming for

    values <- reactiveValues(variable = NA)

    observe({
      CI <- input$InputCI
      ReqDM <- input$InputReqDM
    })
  }
)
```

Cheers,

Comment: use `values$CI <- input$InputCI`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in the server.R part

```
shinyServer(
            function(input, output, session){ #pDMInput is the user input for what DM% they are aiming for
                    CI <- eventReactive(input$submit, {
                            input$InputCI
                    })
                    ReqDM <- eventReactive(input$submit, {
                            input$InputReqDM
                    })

            }
    )
```